# Convert Levenshtein ratio to C++

Tags: python, c++, c

Is there a library for doing the following in C or C++? I don't mean a python library that uses C or C++, but an actual C/C++ library:

```
>>> import Levenshtein
>>> ratio = Levenshtein.ratio('StackOver', 'Stackoverflow')
0.7272727272727273
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to point out, that while this question **is** a resource-only question, the very [`_levenshtein.c`](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/blob/master/Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c) in the source distribution of `python-Levenshtein` itself can be used as a C-only library, provided that it is compiled with `-DNO_PYTHON`:

> Levenshtein.c can be used as a pure C library, too. You only have to define `NO_PYTHON` preprocessor symbol (`-DNO_PYTHON`) when compiling it. The functionality is similar to that of the Python extension. No separate docs are provided yet, RTFS. But they are not interchangeable:
>
> C functions exported when compiling with `-DNO_PYTHON` (see `_levenshtein.h`) are not exported when compiling as a Python extension (and vice versa) Unicode character type used with `-DNO_PYTHON` is `wchar_t`, Python extension uses `Py_UNICODE`, they may be the same but don't count on it

An example:

```
#define NO_PYTHON
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "_levenshtein.h"

double ratio(char *s1, char *s2) {
    size_t l1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t l2 = strlen(s2);
    size_t lsum = l1 + l2;
    if (lsum == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    size_t distance = lev_edit_distance(l1, s1, l2, s2, 1);
    return ((double)lsum - distance) / (lsum);
}

int main() {
    char *str1 = "StackOver";
    char *str2 = "Stackoverflow";

    printf("%.16f\n", ratio(str1, str2));
}
```

Compile `_levenshtein.c` with `-DNO_PYTHON` and link together, and run; output

```
0.7272727272727273
```

Answer (score 3):

What about writing your own basing on the Wikipedia's implementation? Here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C.2B.2B

```
template <class T> unsigned int edit_distance(const T& s1, const T& s2)
{
    const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    vector<vector<unsigned int> > d(len1 + 1, vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));

    d[0][0] = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i) d[i][0] = i;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len2; ++i) d[0][i] = i;

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i)
        for(unsigned int j = 1; j <= len2; ++j)

                      d[i][j] = std::min( std::min(d[i - 1][j] + 1,d[i][j - 1] + 1),
                                          d[i - 1][j - 1] + (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 0 : 1) );
    return d[len1][len2];
}
```

Usage:

```
unsigned int distance = edit_distance<std::string>("StackOver", "Stackoverflow");
```